# How to Connect to FIX Protocol in Node.js without fixparser.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fix-protocol

I am working on integrating the FIX (Financial Information Exchange) protocol in a NodeJs application for financial trading. My goal is to establish a reliable and efficient connection to trading platforms using FIX. I have attempted to use several libraries aimed at facilitating this, including `node-quickfix` and exploring `fixparser` at [fixparser.io](https://fixparser.io/), but encountered some challenges. `fixparser.io` seems like a suitable option; however, it is a paid service, and I am looking for open-source alternatives or solutions that could potentially offer similar functionality.

Here are the specific issues I've encountered:

- With `node-quickfix`, I faced installation issues and also when i checked on there github handle it seems the library is not being maintained from last 2018 i have seen some open questions over there with no replies and also when i try to install this i am getting multiple errors.
- As for `fixparser.io`, while it appears to meet our needs, the cost is a prohibitive factor, and we are exploring other avenues.

Given these challenges, I am seeking advice or recommendations on:

1. Any open-source libraries or tools that are well-suited for connecting to FIX protocol in Node.js, especially those that are actively maintained and documented.
2. Examples or guidance on setting up a FIX connection in Node.js without using `fixparser.io`, including handling session management, message parsing, and sending/receiving messages.
3. Best practices for implementing FIX protocol connectivity in a Node.js environment, particularly from those who have successfully navigated this landscape.

I am open to alternative approaches or any insights into how others have successfully integrated FIX protocol support in their NodeJs applications. Thank you in advance for your help!